# what is the F.G

Tags: beer, fermentation, alcohol-content

The O.G. of my beer is 1.062
this is my recipe 
coopers stout tin 1.7kg
stout enhancer 1.kg (looks like soft brown sugar and other sugars?)
Glucose 500grams
Honey 250 grams
can anyone predict the F.G.

Answer (score 7):

It is impossible to predict YOUR FG. I know nothing about your skill level, your fermentation processes (temp, O2, pitching rates).  I know nothing about the yeast you plan to use.  I know nothing about the true fermentability of the extract and booster you are using.

That said some estimates can be made.  In the best of scenarios if we assume a 65% attenuation rate you would end up around 1.022 OG.  This might be able to be changed up or down a few points depending on the quality of your fermentation regimen.  The glucose and honey CAN ferment out completely but if your fermentation isn't great that 100% ideal drops a bit.

Something that you can do yourself would be to sacrifice two pints of the wort pre-fermentation in a sanitized jar and do a forced fermentation test.  Pitch a full packet of dry yeast into it and ferment it at 75-85F.  Shaking it twice a day. After 5 days you would cool it down to drop the yeast (2 days), then take a sample for gravity check.  That would represent the likely maximum drop you would expect out of that wort in your main batch.  For example, if it fermented down to 1.012 then maybe under ideal conditions you could expect the main batch to be 5-7 points higher than that.